# data submission during form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a form which has two textboxes and a submit button.
on entering data and submitting data gets stored in the database.but if i again refresh the page the same data again gets stored.
How should this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this common problem is to redirect to another ActionResult, where you inform of the success/failure of the form submission.

Also, try to submit a ViewModel instance (see strongly typed views), not form values. That simplifies data validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a [PRG redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to a confirmation / thank you page.